# How do I accurately convert a uchar into a float32 and vice versa using neon intrinsics

Tags: intrinsics

I am working on optimizing a bit of c++ code for video filtering and using intrinsics to do so. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to type caste my values while still maintaining accuracy when loading and storing into vectors of different types.

I need to store 4 values of my uchar vector img into a float32x4_t vector.

The first method I used was:

```
  float32x4_t first_val = {(float32_t)img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*j],
                                (float32_t)img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*(j + 1)],
                                (float32_t)img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*(j + 2)],
                                (float32_t)img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*(j + 3)]
                                };
```

which works but is bottlenecking my speed now.  So I tried:

```
float32x4_t first_val = vld1q_f32((float32_t*)&img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*j]);
```

which does not work.  I suspect it's because it's transforming 4 of my 8bit pixels into one float and essentially interpreting it as garbage.

I'm considering using vreinterpret{q}_dsttype_srctype to avoid this problem, but the example code seems only capable of reinterpreting a var type of x size into another vartype of the same size.  I'm encountering the same problem when storing as well as loading.

If anyone knows the correct method for accurately going from uchar -> float32 and float32->uchar please help.

Answer (score 0):

The indexing calculation to the image data is rather expensive and you are doing it 4 times. I'm assuming the data[] is being transferred in sequence but I can't tell due to lack of code. This assumption is based on the fact you tried to use vld1q_f32() in the second example and this expects the data to be in sequence.

Anyway, try this:

```
uchar* p = &img.data[STEP0*i + STEP1*j];

float32x4_t first_val = {(float32_t)*p++,
                            (float32_t)*p++,
                            (float32_t)*p++,
                            (float32_t)*p++
                            };
```

If you can get the first line initialised outside the loop then you should see a dramatic increase.

If you want it even more faster then investigate UNION keyword bearing in mind this could well be more trouble than it is worth. Personally I wouldn't recommend it.

vld1q_f32() seems to be for the same format and not mixture 2 data types. Your reasoning as to why it is not working is how I suspect what happening.

Comment: I've tried this and while it has some speed improvement, it's also distorting my video.  Is it possible to message you to go more into detail and provide you with my code?

Comment: If it is not working then the bytes aren't in sequence. You need to provide more source code. I suspect the solution is setting up 4 uchar* variables. As long as they can be initialised outside the inner loop then this speed improvement can happen. Feel free to send a message.